# Ui_MainWindow has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm writing a program which will have multiple windows. I have a main program (attached) that calls the Ui files (that have been converted into .py). The main window and customise window open correctly (the first two listed) but neither the third or fourth windows open correctly, giving me the error

```
'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'show'
```

The main program;

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwin = main_menu_ui.Ui_MainWindow()
    mainwin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def openCustomise(self):
    customiseOpen = question_set_menu_ui.Ui_MainWindow()
    customiseOpen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def openQuiz(self):
    quizOpen = quiz_window_ui.Ui_MainWindow()
    quizOpen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def addNewSet(self):
    addNewOpen = question_set_edit_ui.Ui_MainWindow()
    addNewOpen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm learning Qt/Python for college.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-generated UI class that you are importing extends `object` and doesn't have a `show` method (open up the .py file for yourself and verify this).

In general, you should structure your GUIs like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from layout_file import main_menu_ui

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = main_menu_ui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwin = MyForm()
    mainwin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You import your UI from your autogenerated UI file.  You have a class that contains your GUI logic.  It then sets up your UI layout from your imported UI in its `__init__()` method.